# Cant install DHCP in webmin Help!

Tags: webmin

I installed ubuntu 18.04 today and after I installed webmin I can't install dhcp-server.

How can I debug/fix this?

[image]

Comment: The package is called `isc-dhcp-server`  not `dhcp3-server` It was renamed to that in 2011 or 2012.

Comment: But how i cant change it in webmin, i have to install it from webmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *System -> Software Pacakges* then select the radio button for *Package from APT*.  In the box type in `isc-dhcp-server` then click the red Install button below.

[image]

Comment: Tnx @Terrance u saved me :).

Comment: @Ubuntu_addict You're welcome!  You can also click on the Search APT button to the right and type in part of the name of whatever package you are looking for then click the search in the new window and it will show you the package you are looking for and all you should have to do is click on it for it to add it.